# Optimizing the speed of importing data from Excel - IronXL vs. Office Interop

Tags: c#, excel, performance, excel-interop, ironxl

I wrote a programme that imports data from an .xlsx file and then creates many XML files based on the imported data. Now, at first I tried doing that using IronXL but then I realized that it's not a free option if I wanted to publish my programme, so I tried doing the same thing using Office Interop. So now I've got two codes, both do the same thing and they do it right, but IronXL method is way faster (~8 seconds vs ~40 seconds checked for two worksheets, but overall I will have around 10-15 worksheets so the time will obviously get longer). Can I optimize my code in any way or is it just that IronXL method will be faster and there's nothing I can do about it?
Here's my code for Office Interop:

```
static public void LoadExcelDataInterop()
        {
            //Normally floats are imported as numbers with a comma, e.g. 12,5 rather than 12.5
            //Everywhere else in the code, the correct format is 12.5
            //When I printed the weapons' data into a file, the format was with a comma and this caused errors
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Outward - r2modman\Mods\OutwardDe\profiles\Outward\BepInEx\plugins\Outward_Mod_Weapons_ValuesToImport.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
            {
                if (ws.Name == "Swords_1h" || ws.Name == "Swords_2h"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Axes_1h"    || ws.Name == "Axes_2h"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Maces_1h"   || ws.Name == "Maces_2h"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Halberds"   || ws.Name == "Staves"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Spears"     || ws.Name == "Gauntlets"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Bows"       || ws.Name == "Shields"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Chakrams"   || ws.Name == "Daggers"     || ws.Name == "Pistols"
                    )
                {

                    for (int x = 2; x > 0; x++)
                    {
                        var cell = ws.Cells[x, 2] as Excel.Range;
                        string cell_name = (string)cell.Value;

                        if (cell_name == null) { break; }
                        else
                        {
                            dict_Weapons.Add(cell_name, new SL_Weapon(wb, ws, cell));
                        }
                    }
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws);
            }

            wb.Close(false, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
```

And here's the constructor of SL_Weapon for Interop:

```
public SL_Weapon(Excel.Workbook wb, Excel.Worksheet ws, Excel.Range cell)
            {
                StatsHolder = new SL_WeaponStats
                {
                    Damage_Bonus = new float[9],
                    Damage_Resistance = new float[9],
                };
                var SH = ((SL_WeaponStats)StatsHolder);
                SH.BaseDamage = new List<SL_Damage>();
                Effects = new List<OE_Effect>();

                for (int i = 1; i <= ws.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    var heading = ws.Cells[1, i] as Excel.Range;
                    string headingName = (string)heading.Value;

                    var workingCell = ws.Cells[cell.Row, heading.Column] as Excel.Range;
                    var workingCell_nextCell = ws.Cells[cell.Row, heading.Column + 1] as Excel.Range;

                    if (headingName == null) { break; }
                    else if (workingCell.Value == null) { continue; }
                    else
                    {
                        if (headingName == "Name") { Name = (string)workingCell.Value; }
                        if (headingName == "ID") { Target_ItemID = New_ItemID = (int)workingCell.Value; }
                        
                        if (headingName == "DMG Physical") { SH.BaseDamage.Add(new SL_Damage { Damage = (float)workingCell.Value, Type = "Physical" }); }
                        if (headingName == "DMG 2") { SH.BaseDamage.Add(new SL_Damage { Damage = (float)workingCell.Value, Type = (string)workingCell_nextCell.Value }); }
                        if (headingName == "DMG 3") { SH.BaseDamage.Add(new SL_Damage { Damage = (float)workingCell.Value, Type = (string)workingCell_nextCell.Value }); }

                        //OPTION 1 for StatsHolder fields - doesn't work, throws an error ('Object of type 'System.Single' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32')
                        /*
                        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(SL_WeaponStats).GetFields();
                        foreach (var field in fields)
                        {
                            if (headingName == field.Name) { field.SetValue(StatsHolder, (float)workingCell.Value); }
                        }
                        */

                        //OPTION 2 for StatsHolder fields
                        if (headingName == "MaxDurability") { SH.MaxDurability = (int)workingCell.Value; }
                        if (headingName == "RawWeight") { SH.RawWeight = (float)workingCell.Value; }
                        if (headingName == "BaseValue") { SH.BaseValue = (int)workingCell.Value; }

                        if (headingName == "StamCost") { SH.StamCost = (float)workingCell.Value; }
                        if (headingName == "AttackSpeed") { SH.AttackSpeed = (float)workingCell.Value; }
                        if (headingName == "Impact") { SH.Impact = (float)workingCell.Value; }
                        
                        if (workingCell_nextCell.Value != null) 
                        {
                            if (headingName == "Effect 1" || headingName == "Effect 2" || headingName == "Effect 3")
                            { Effects.Add(new OE_Effect { StatusEffect = (string)workingCell.Value, Buildup = (int)workingCell_nextCell.Value }); }

                        }
                    }

                    foreach (Excel.Worksheet worksheet in wb.Worksheets)
                    {
                        if (worksheet.Name == "Damage_BonusOrRes")
                        {
                            var item_dmgBonus = ((SL_EquipmentStats)StatsHolder).Damage_Bonus;
                            var item_dmgResistance = ((SL_EquipmentStats)StatsHolder).Damage_Resistance;

                            for (int x = 2; x < 10; x++ )
                            {
                                Excel.Range workingCell2 = worksheet.Cells[x, 1] as Excel.Range;
                                string workingCell2Name = (string)workingCell2.Value;
                                if (workingCell2Name == null) { break; }
                                else if (workingCell2.Value.ToString() == cell.Value.ToString())
                                {
                                    for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
                                    {
                                        if ((worksheet.Cells[x, y + 2] as Excel.Range).Value != null)
                                        {
                                            item_dmgBonus[y] = (float)(worksheet.Cells[x, y + 2] as Excel.Range).Value;
                                        }
                                        if ((worksheet.Cells[x, y + 8] as Excel.Range).Value != null)
                                        {
                                            item_dmgResistance[y] = (float)(worksheet.Cells[x, y + 8] as Excel.Range).Value;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here's the code for IronXL:

```
public static void LoadExcelDataIronXL()
        {
            //Normally IronXL imports floats as numbers with a comma, e.g. 12,5 rather than 12.5
            //Everywhere else in the code, the correct format is 12.5
            //When I printed the weapons' data into a file, the format was with a comma
            //And later when I copied it to the other Programme, I was getting errors because the format should be with a dot
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;


            WorkBook wb = WorkBook.Load("D:/Outward - r2modman/Mods/OutwardDe/profiles/Outward/BepInEx/plugins/Outward_Mod_Weapons_ValuesToImport.xlsx");

            void LoadExcel_Weapons()
            {
                foreach (var ws in wb.WorkSheets)
                {
                    if (ws.Name == "Swords_1h" || ws.Name == "Swords_2h"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Axes_1h"    || ws.Name == "Axes_2h"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Maces_1h"   || ws.Name == "Maces_2h"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Halberds"   || ws.Name == "Staves"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Spears"     || ws.Name == "Gauntlets"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Bows"       || ws.Name == "Shields"
                    //     || ws.Name == "Chakrams"   || ws.Name == "Daggers"     || ws.Name == "Pistols"
                       )
                    {
                        foreach (var item in ws.Columns[1])
                        {
                            if (item.IsEmpty) { break; }
                            else if (item.RowIndex == 0) { continue; }
                            else
                            {
                                dict_Weapons.Add(item.Value.ToString(), new SL_Weapon(wb, ws.Name, item));item.Value.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            LoadExcel_Weapons();
        }
```

And the constructor of SL_weapon for IronXL:

```
public SL_Weapon(WorkBook wb, string worksheetName, Cell cell)
            {
                WorkSheet ws = wb.GetWorkSheet(worksheetName);
                RangeRow row = ws.Rows[cell.RowIndex];
                StatsHolder = new SL_WeaponStats
                {
                    Damage_Bonus = new float[9],
                    Damage_Resistance = new float[9],
                };
                var SH = ((SL_WeaponStats)StatsHolder);
                SH.BaseDamage = new List<SL_Damage>();
                Effects = new List<OE_Effect>();

                foreach (var heading in ws.Rows[0])
                {
                    var headingColumn = heading.ColumnIndex;
                    var headingName = heading.ToString();

                    if (headingName == "Name") { Name = row.Columns[headingColumn].ToString(); }
                    if (headingName == "ID") { Target_ItemID = New_ItemID = row.Columns[headingColumn].IntValue; }

                    if (headingName == "DMG Physical") { SH.BaseDamage.Add(new SL_Damage { Damage = row.Columns[headingColumn].FloatValue, Type = "Physical" }); }
                    if (headingName == "DMG 2") { SH.BaseDamage.Add(new SL_Damage { Damage = row.Columns[headingColumn].FloatValue, Type = row.Columns[headingColumn + 1].ToString() }); }
                    if (headingName == "DMG 3") { SH.BaseDamage.Add(new SL_Damage { Damage = row.Columns[headingColumn].FloatValue, Type = row.Columns[headingColumn + 1].ToString() }); }
                    
                    if (headingName == "MaxDurability")     { SH.MaxDurability = row.Columns[headingColumn].IntValue; }
                    if (headingName == "RawWeight")         { SH.RawWeight = row.Columns[headingColumn].FloatValue; }
                    if (headingName == "BaseValue")         { SH.BaseValue = row.Columns[headingColumn].IntValue; }

                    if (headingName == "StamCost")          { SH.StamCost = row.Columns[headingColumn].FloatValue; }
                    if (headingName == "AttackSpeed")       { SH.AttackSpeed = row.Columns[headingColumn].FloatValue; }
                    if (headingName == "Impact")            { SH.Impact = row.Columns[headingColumn].FloatValue; }
                    

                    if (headingName == "Effect 1") { Effects.Add(new OE_Effect { StatusEffect = row.Columns[headingColumn].ToString(), Buildup = row.Columns[headingColumn + 1].IntValue }); }
                    if (headingName == "Effect 2") { Effects.Add(new OE_Effect { StatusEffect = row.Columns[headingColumn].ToString(), Buildup = row.Columns[headingColumn + 1].IntValue }); }
                    if (headingName == "Effect 3") { Effects.Add(new OE_Effect { StatusEffect = row.Columns[headingColumn].ToString(), Buildup = row.Columns[headingColumn + 1].IntValue }); }

                }

                var ws_DmgBonusOrRes = wb.GetWorkSheet("Damage_BonusOrRes");
                var item_dmgBonus = ((SL_EquipmentStats)StatsHolder).Damage_Bonus;
                var item_dmgResistance = ((SL_EquipmentStats)StatsHolder).Damage_Resistance;

                foreach (var cell1 in ws_DmgBonusOrRes.Columns[0])
                {
                    if (cell1.IsEmpty) { break; }
                    else if (cell1.RowIndex == 0) { continue; }
                    else if (cell1.Value.ToString() == cell.ToString())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                        {
                            item_dmgBonus[i] = ws_DmgBonusOrRes.Rows[cell1.RowIndex].Columns[i + 1].FloatValue;
                            item_dmgResistance[i] = ws_DmgBonusOrRes.Rows[cell1.RowIndex].Columns[i + 7].FloatValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You may consider using NuGet package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.8.1). Using the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#related-tools) will be helpful when using OpenXml.

Answer (score 0):

[Marcin Pagórek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17760199/marcin-pag%c3%b3rek) is correct that IronXL is faster than Office Interop, but a data reader that just caches cell values from the XML *will* be faster still.

However [IronXL](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/excel/) is a multi-purpose tool that provides the entire ecosystem of Excel editing and conversion tools, that can parse and edit per your requirements (not a speed-orientation data reader).

We (Disclaimer: I work for Iron Software) like the idea of adding a fast reading-only option to increase the speed of IronXL even more, so it has been logged as a feature request.

IronXL is free for development, though commercial use does require a license starting at a low $499. Licensing information is shown at https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/excel/licensing/

Answer (score -1):

IronXL uses NPOI internally. If you download the nuget package and decompile the dll, you'll see that it has embedded code from: NPOI, BouncyCastle, Newtonsoft,  ICSharpCode, ImageSharp, and probably others. It seems to me that they have taken a bunch of open-source code and packaged it up to make it look standalone so that they can charge money for it. I don't have any issue with charging money for your own work, but when you're trying to sell someone else's work that feels a bit shady.

Anyway... to answer your question about Excel performance. The fastest library for reading Excel data (that I'm aware of) is [Sylvan.Data.Excel](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan.Data.Excel). I've benchmarked it against several other popular .NET Excel libraries, and [it is the fastest by quite a wide margin](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Benchmarks/blob/main/docs/ExcelReaderBenchmarks.md). I should also point out that I'm the author of this library, so will probably want to verify my performance claims yourself.

My library exposes Excel data as a DbDataReader, the standard ADO.NET abstract class for reading data records. You might also check out [Sylvan.Data](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan/blob/main/docs/Data/Sylvan.Data.md), which provides a data binder that can easily bind a DbDataReader to .NET objects.

With Sylvan.Data.Excel and Sylvan.Data your code might be as simple as:

```
using var reader = ExcelDataReader.Create("mydata.xlsx");
List<Weapon> weapons = reader.GetRecords<Weapon>().ToList();
```

It will likely be a bit more complex than that, because it looks like your binding code has some complexity to it, but you shouldn't have any trouble adapting that to my libraries.